# PostgreSQL: for duplicating values for another user insert record from same table which has unique id

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-insert

I have table called customer_config. there I have four records.

```
id  customer_name   cust_id currency_code
1      test            1         (null)
2      alpha           1         (null)
3      beta            1         (null)
4      clone           1         (null)
```

id column should be not null and unique.
I would like to clone all these record to another custmer ie : `cust_id =2`;
I was trying with below query like

```
INSERT INTO customer_config(cust_id, customer_name, currency_code)
SELECT 2, customer_name, currency_code
FROM customer_config
WHERE cust_id = 1;
```

here I cant introduce/update  customer_config table by adding sequence.

with of any logic may I get the records be inserted.

your help will be appreciated

Note:

> Error was like
>   17:55:38  [INSERT - 0 rows, 0.583 secs]  [Code: 0, SQL State: 23502]  ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
>     Detail: Failing row contains (4, null, sslProtocol, 1, SSL, null).
>   ... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 rows affected, exec/fetch time: 0.583/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 1 errors]

Answer (score 0):

Your `id` column has apparently no default value. Thus you must insert its value explicitly. If you have a sequence for this column you can try:

```
INSERT INTO customer_config(id, cust_id, customer_name, currency_code)
SELECT NEXTVAL('id_sequence'), 2, customer_name, currency_code
FROM customer_config
WHERE cust_id = 1;
```

where `id_sequence` is the name of that sequence.

Comment: "2" parameter is redundant, since you use NEXTVAL

Comment: @MaratSafin: No, this is for `cust_id`. See column list in `INTO` clause.

Comment: Оh, sorry, my bad

Comment: I can't introduce new sequence for this table.

Comment: @parasuramans: But you need a value for your `id` column. Where does the ids in this table come from?

Comment: @clemens id can be serial with reference to this (customer_config)  table. Need with out any DDL changes.